# what is the difference with NgForm and FormGroupDirective?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I tried below code to reset which works fine.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="createRecord(formDirective)" #formDirective="ngForm">
</form>
resetForm(form:  FormGroupDirective)  {         
     form.resetForm();  
 }
```

what is the difference if I do like this?

```
<form #myform="ngForm"></form>
resetForm(form:  NgForm)  {         
     form.resetForm();  
 }
```

Comment: The first is a reactive form and the second is a template-driven form: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#key-differences You should remove _"what is the better way to reset a form?"_ This makes your question opinion-based.

Comment: Thank you, I will update my question.